# Calling webservice from another webservice in same war - apache cxf

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, httpclient

I have two webs services or endpoints having one method each and each method is mapped with one URL. I am calling one webservice URL from REST client and in this method i want to call method in another web service which is mapped to URL. How can this be achieved in apache CXf ?

I tried using HttpClient to call another webservice from one but I am getting 404, if I use complete URL and getting 302 code but no response if I use relative URL. what might be issue and what is correct approach ?

Comment: 302 is not an error code. If the 2 services are in the same war, why do you go over web services? Sounds like an expensive thing

Comment: Thanks David. So how do I make a call to other end point ? Can i create instance of other class and call method ? For example one service for authentication and other for doing operation. Now when operation service is called I want to authenticate first and do operation.

Comment: @user7185698 just inject the endpoint instance into the other endpoint. Or define an object with the bussiness logic and inject it into both endpoints. This is not a CXF problem. If you have defined the endpoints using spring configuration or annotations and you do not know where are the instances, then show the code so people could advise you

Answer (score 1):

You can try to call directly the other controller without httprequest.
for example you have the two next controllers with all annotations you need

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/a")
public class A{
     @RequestMapping(...)
    public void toCall(){
        //your code
    }
}
```

you want to call the method `toCall` of controller A from controller B

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/b")
public class B{
     @RequestMapping(...)
    public void method(){
        A a = new A();
        a.toCall();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks nasim, my question is toCall() method accepts queryparam and raw data as inputs, how this be managed from a.toCall() ?

Comment: put your arguments directly like params of the method toCall(param1,param2,...).